# JWT Handler for .NET 4.5 throws error: GetIssuerName with single parameter is not supported

Tags: wif, saml, acs, jwt

I've just implemented this JSON Web Token Handler for .Net 4.5 library described here:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/20/introducing-the-developer-preview-of-the-json-web-token-handler-for-the-microsoft-net-framework-4-5-2/

I have an ACS service that's supposed to be returning a JWT token to my application. However, at the point when I should be getting the token returned to my app (when the browser is redirected to my relying party's return uri), I instead get this exception:

> WIF10200: GetIssuerName with single parameter is not supported. Call:
>   'GetIssuerName( SecurityToken securityToken, string issuer )'.

I don't think this is a problem directly with my code; because if I do a solution-wide search, "GetIssuerName" is not in my solution. I think it might have something to do with the certificate issuers WIF wants to trust, but I've followed the instructions in the article I linked above about importing the certificate from the ACS site's FederationMetadata... and I'm utterly stumped on this one.

Strangely enough, when I change my Relying Party token type from JWT to SAML 1 or 2, my relying party's Return Uri is never hit, I'm just redirected back to my realm error free. I would expect to finally land on my Return Uri. If someone could explain either phenomenon to me, it would help tremendously!

UPDATE

The GetIssuerName method in .NET 4.5 is part of the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry class (there's also a System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry class with the same method, but that's not the one I'm working with).

From looking at the metadata, there are 2 overridden methods with this name in the class:

```
public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken);
public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken, string requestedIssuerName);
```

The error I'm getting from WIF seems to be coming directly from the first method listed there, as you can see from the stack trace below. With my relying party returning JWT, something somewhere is supposed to be calling the second method, whose signature has a second parameter, but is calling the first. I wish I knew how to change it.

> [NotSupportedException: WIF10200: GetIssuerName with single parameter
>   is not supported. Call: 'GetIssuerName( SecurityToken securityToken,
>   string issuer )'.]
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry.GetIssuerName(SecurityToken
>   securityToken) +156
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT.JWTSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateIssuer(JWTSecurityToken
>   jwt, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) +1303
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT.JWTSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(JWTSecurityToken
>   jwt, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) +278
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT.JWTSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken
>   token) +2248
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken(SecurityToken
>   token) +135
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.TokenReceiver.AuthenticateToken(SecurityToken
>   token, Boolean ensureBearerToken, String endpointUri) +502
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase
>   request) +1508
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args) +700
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165